# How to create an application to update tile periodically?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am developing an application for Windows Phone 7.1 and I want to update the tile information.

So I need to know two things:

- How do I run a task in the background?
- How do I change the image/text on a tile?

Are there some basic examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample shows exactly what you're after:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Shell-Tile-Schedule-589f628e

From the page:

> This sample demonstrates how to update the background image on the front of the Tile on a regular schedule.